# How to change Super + L screen lock command?

Tags: greeter, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When you press **Super + L**, it locks the screen. This shortcut is not available in the keyboard settings to change, for some reason. I'd love to change the command `dm-tool -lock` command that it executes to `xscreensaver-command -lock`.

Does anyone know where I would change that? Thanks!

Comment: Is there an option available in elementary tweaks? sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily & sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks